# macro with structure definition missing '()' - QAC error

Tags: c, qa-c

Here is the structure i wrote

```
#define struct_macro(struct_type_name,struct_name) \
typedef struct struct_type_name                    \
{                                                  \
   int a;                                          \
   char b;                                         \
} struct_name
```

this is throwing QAC error with '()' missing.

But with '()' there is compilation error.

```
#define struct_macro(struct_type_name,struct_name) \
typedef struct struct_type_name                    \
{                                                  \
   int a;                                          \
   char b;                                         \
} (struct_name)
```

Is there any workaround??

Comment: Did you cut and paste your example into your post and there are multiple typos.

Comment: edited as suggested, thank you!

Comment: Have you got this resolved?  If not, I think it would help if you created an MCVE ([MCVE]) which showed code where you define the macro and where you use it.  Ensure that the code generates the error you're seeing.  Normally, you should put at least a space between the `)` of the function-like macro name and arguments and the replacement text.  When you have backslash-newline, there is no space.  However, I don't think that should be the problem (but it might be).

Comment: As currently written, you can't use the macro twice in a single scope because it creates the same structure tag each time because you've got a typo in `strct_type_name` (vs `struct_type_name`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define struct_macro(struct_type_name,struct_name) typedef struct struct_type_name\
{\
   int a;\
   char b;\
} struct_name\
```

Comment: @rakshi you have many spelling errors in the code you have provided - so I am not surprised that you have a problem compiling and QAing it.

Comment: i corrected as suggested, thank you. Any possible solutions are appreciated.